# Using the Input tag as a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, event-handling

in my HTML file, I am using an image to represent a button which the player can click. This button works as a way to load into the game. When the user clicks it, I want the webpage to run my JavaScript file.

Currently, the input tag is handled like this:

```
<input type="image" src="Images/start.jpg" height='200' width='350' alt='Something went wrong loading the images. Update your Internet plugins and try again.'/>
```

I've checked on quite a few websites, but the ones I've seen have told me that onclick (what I assume I could use) is a button tag aspect only.

Am I wrong about this? What would be the simplest way to execute my script?

Comment: Where is the javascript you want to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` works fine with `type="image"` too. You can do that like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="Images/start.jpg" height='200' width='350' alt='Something went wrong loading the images. Update your Internet plugins and try again.' onclick="yourScript();"/>
```

JS:

```
function yourScript()
    {
        //your JS here
    }
```

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585804/onclick-with-input-type-image

Comment: My script is set up like this:
INIT()
UPDATE()
function INIT()
{
 //Stuff
}
function UPDATE()
{
 //Stuff
}
How would I call the whole script, or is that not possible?

Comment: Just add that to the "your JS here" section as shown above Taylor.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click handler to an input element of type image works just fine.

---

#### Demo

```js
function INIT() {
   alert('INITIALIZE GAME');
}

function UPDATE() {
   alert('UPDATE GAME');
}

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", function() {
   INIT();
   UPDATE();
});
```

```html
<input type="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsBv.png?s=328&g=1" height='100' width='100' alt='Something went wrong loading the images. Update your Internet plugins and try again.' id="startGame" />
```